# Use parameter in DAG body airflow

Tags: python-3.x, airflow

I want the most 'pythonic' way to take a list as a parameter in a DAG, and call some task for each item in the list. There appears to be many ways to take parameters in a DAG, but I can't get any of them to work. Ideally I would like something along the lines of:

```py
@task
def process(item: str):
    # Does something
    pass

@dag(dag_id="with_params")
def with_params(items: list[str]):
    for item in items:
        process(item)

with_params(["a", "b", "c"])
```

With the method written above, I get the error `DagParam object is not iterable`. Using the method `params={items=Param(["a", "b", "c"])}` in the DAG decorator does not seem to work, as I have not been able to access it through `**kwargs`.

Answer (score 1):

You could utilize [dynamic task mapping](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/authoring-and-scheduling/dynamic-task-mapping.html) for this

```py
from airflow.decorators import task
from airflow.models import DAG
from datetime import datetime

@task
def process(item: str):
    print(f'{item=}')
    pass

with DAG('with_params',
          schedule_interval=None,
          start_date=datetime(2023, 2, 13),
          catchup=False,
          ):

    process.expand(item=["a", "b", "c"])
```

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of completeness I will also add my two cents here, although @sleep-deprived-bulbasaur's answer is valid in my opinion.

The problem lays in part with the way you've declared the parameters using Param. Param in Airflow is used to perform parameter validation. From my experience, an array in a Param can either mean that you want to delcare a parameter that can have multiple types (i.e. `Param(5, type=["null", "number", "string"])`) or that can assume a fixed set of values, such as an enum (i.e. `Param("foo", enum=["foo", "bar", 42])`).

When declaring `params` in the decorator, you can access them from within the tasks, not the DAG itself:

```
@task
def process(params: dict = None):
    items = params["items"]
    print(items)
    
@dag(
    dag_id="with_params",
    params={"items": ["a", "b", "c"]}
)
def with_params():
    process()
```

Hope this helps!